# How can I stop a Timer?

Tags: java, android, timer

I have a simple question, how can I stop timer?

```
 Button bCancel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bt1);
 bCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent("com.jom.testcdt2.CANCELCLASS"));

        }
    });


    final Thread logoTimer = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try {
                int logoTimer = 0;
                while (logoTimer < 10000) {
                    sleep(100);
                    logoTimer = logoTimer + 100;

                }
                startActivity(new Intent("com.jom.testcdt2.CLEARSCREEN"));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally{
                finish();
            }
        }
    };
    logoTimer.start();    
}
```

When I press button bCancel, it starts a new activity, but timer is still running and after 10 seconds it starts CLEARSCREEN. On click I want timer to stop. How can I do that?

Comment: have you tried logoTimer.interrupt()?

Comment: @JanOIMajti assign a flag variable and if it accounts to true, break the while loop

Comment: Loop is for using sound every second

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend using a `CountDownTimer`:

```
final CountDownTimer myTimer = new CountDownTimer(10000, 5000) {
@Override
public void onFinish() {
    //DO SOMETHING AFTER 10 000 ms
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
    //DO SOMETHING EVERY 5 000 ms until stopped
    }
}
myTimer.start() //Starts it
myTimer.cancel() //Stops it
```

And instead of writing

```
(new Intent("com.jom.testcdt2.CANCELCLASS")
```

you should use

```
(new Intent(YOURCLASS.this, CancelClass.class)
```

Comment: Thanks, it´s working. I use CountDownTimer, and when u want to stop timer it must be myTimer.cancel();

Comment: Oh, you are right, I will edit that. Good to hear this worked for you!

Comment: (new Intent(YOURCLASS.this, CancelClass.class) Thanks for that too, it´s easier way.

Answer (score 3):

Could you try to have a boolean value that you check in the while loop, and set it to true when you press the cancel button?

```
boolean pressedCancel = false;
.... 

while (logoTimer < 10000 && !pressedCancel) {
    ....
```

Comment: yes, i tried, but in onClick i somehow could´t set it on true